# How to set environment variable in springboot integration junit test case

Tags: junit, mockito

We are strugguling with setting environmet variable for passing junit integration test cases in springboot micro service . If I set environment variable in intellij tool , then all test cases are passed. But i need this environment variable to be set in junit test case level. I will approtiate your help on this if you provide solution for this issue.